# disable Progressbar accessibility event trigger

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

In Android when Talkback is enabled and you use a progressbar in a view. then each time the progressbar is updated, then also an accessibility event is triggered to inform the user that there has been some progress update. However this causes that talkback is constantly notifying the user of updates because the progress is constantly updating. Is there some way to disable or suppress the chain of events that cause Talback to speak when a progressbar updates?

Comment: TalkBack hasn't had that behavior for a long time. Are you sure you're using an up-to-date version of TalkBack?

Comment: @alanv well, my device says Talkback 4.2.0. And the play store doesn't find a newer version, So, as far as I'm aware, I'm using the latest version. But Android 5 appears to be working. pre Lollipop seems like an issue

Comment: Yeah, that's the latest version. TalkBack should be ignoring those events unless the ProgressBar has accessibility focus. You can manually prevent them by no-op'ing TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED accessibility events, but you shouldn't need to.